# Group .txt files based on text inside them

Tags: powershell

I don't know how to code so I asked ChatGPT to come up with a script for me. I need to group hundred of thousands poker hand history files into their respective buy in folder. They are currently all mixed up in a single folder. I'll put a copy of what a poker hand history looks like.

```
PokerStars Hand #212603518891: Tournament #2869138653, $30+$3 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level I (15/30) - 2020/04/24 1:00:02 ET
Table '2869138653 1' 9-max Seat #3 is the button
Seat 3: klutke21 (5000 in chips) 
Seat 4: Rochinha2011 (5000 in chips) 
Seat 5: Septenzo (5000 in chips) 
Seat 6: Djuk7 (5000 in chips) 
Seat 7: Royal Krab (5000 in chips) 
Seat 8: katuwo (5000 in chips) 
Seat 9: Coronavirus101 (5000 in chips) 
klutke21: posts the ante 4
Rochinha2011: posts the ante 4
Septenzo: posts the ante 4
Djuk7: posts the ante 4
Royal Krab: posts the ante 4
katuwo: posts the ante 4
Coronavirus101: posts the ante 4
Rochinha2011: posts small blind 15
Septenzo: posts big blind 30
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Djuk7: folds 
Royal Krab: folds 
katuwo: raises 60 to 90
Coronavirus101: folds 
klutke21: calls 90
Rochinha2011: folds 
Septenzo: folds 
*** FLOP *** [4d 2h 6s]
katuwo: bets 90
klutke21: calls 90
*** TURN *** [4d 2h 6s] [5h]
katuwo: bets 120
klutke21: calls 120
*** RIVER *** [4d 2h 6s 5h] [Kh]
katuwo: checks 
klutke21: bets 390
katuwo: calls 390
*** SHOW DOWN ***
klutke21: shows [Ac Td] (high card Ace)
katuwo: shows [Ts Th] (a pair of Tens)
katuwo collected 1453 from pot
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 1453 | Rake 0 
Board [4d 2h 6s 5h Kh]
Seat 3: klutke21 (button) showed [Ac Td] and lost with high card Ace
Seat 4: Rochinha2011 (small blind) folded before Flop
Seat 5: Septenzo (big blind) folded before Flop
Seat 6: Djuk7 folded before Flop (didn't bet)
Seat 7: Royal Krab folded before Flop (didn't bet)
Seat 8: katuwo showed [Ts Th] and won (1453) with a pair of Tens
Seat 9: Coronavirus101 folded before Flop (didn't bet)
```

So the only relevant information is BUY IN. I ONLY NEED TO GROUP THEM BY BUYIN. IF SAME BUY IN, SAME FOLDER.

So ChatGPT came up with this script:

```
# Diretório que contém os arquivos .txt
$diretorio = "D:\HAND HISTORY\POKERSTARS\HH DEALER\2020\4\2020 - 04"

# Loop através dos arquivos .txt no diretório
Get-ChildItem -Path $diretorio -Filter *.txt | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Processando arquivo: $($_.Name)"  # Adicione esta linha para indicar o arquivo sendo processado
    $caminhoArquivo = $_.FullName
    $conteudoArquivo = Get-Content $caminhoArquivo

    # Procurar pela linha que contém o valor do buy-in
    $linhaBuyIn = $conteudoArquivo | Select-String -Pattern "\$([\d.]+) USD" | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Groups[0].Value }

    if ($linhaBuyIn) {
        $buyIn = [float]$linhaBuyIn -replace '\D', ''  # Extrai o buy-in como um número decimal

        # Crie uma pasta para o buy-in se ela não existir
        $pastaBuyIn = Join-Path -Path $diretorio -ChildPath ("\$" + $buyIn)
        if (-not (Test-Path $pastaBuyIn -PathType Container)) {
            Write-Host "Criando pasta: $pastaBuyIn"  # Adicione esta linha para indicar a criação da pasta
            New-Item -Path $pastaBuyIn -ItemType Directory
        }

        # Move o arquivo para a pasta do buy-in correspondente
        $caminhoDestino = Join-Path -Path $pastaBuyIn -ChildPath $_.Name
        Write-Host "Movendo arquivo para: $caminhoDestino"  # Adicione esta linha para indicar o movimento do arquivo
        Move-Item -Path $caminhoArquivo -Destination $caminhoDestino
    }
}
```

But it's not working, it's not even running. I'm using Powershell. I've enabled scripts in it using the recommended function. I also ran a writing into a file test script and it worked, so I'm really lost why this is not working.

I expected it to read a file, find it's buyin and go to the next file. This is also important. It doesn't need to read the whole .txt, only find it's buy in. Unfortunally the script doesn't run

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I can't see an example of a 'BUY IN' in your example poker history, so I don't know if "\$([\d.]+) USD" would match the condition. Please supply an example of a 'BUY IN' in the log/history.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an optimized version of your code. It assumes:

- Only the first line of each file must be examined.
- A representative example buy-in value is `$30+$3 USD`, and all buy-in values are structured like that, with the `USD` part fixed.
- The part before  `USD` is to be used as the name of the target subdirectory (e.g. `'$30+3'`)

```bash
$dir = 'D:\HAND HISTORY\POKERSTARS\HH DEALER\2020\4\2020 - 04'

Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dir -Filter *.txt | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Processing file: $($_.Name)"
    if (($_ | Get-Content -First 1) -match '(\$[\d+$]+) USD') {
      $destDirName = $Matches.1  # e.g. '$30+$3'
      Write-Host "Moving to subdirectory: $destDirName"
      $_ | Move-Item -WhatIf -Destination (New-Item -Force -Type Directory (Join-Path $dir $destDirName)) 
    }
}
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>